# Error While using IsExistingObject Method to check component exists through webDav URL in Core Service

Tags: 2011, core-service, webdav

I have an issue when I tried to check the component existence through WebDav URL using method IsExistingObject

Error message:

```
A database error occurred while executing Stored Procedure "EDA_ORG_ITEMS_GETIDSFROMPATHS".
```

Is there any Constraints on the WebDav URL Length? When I restrict my Component Title it is working. Even I'm getting same issue when we browse the URL?

**Update:**

When ever I reduce the WebDav URL(Publication to component Path) then IsExisting Object is working as expected.

Comment: Can you post your WebDAV URL and title of the component which you getting an issue?

Comment: Are you using some special characters in title?

Comment: I think Special characters are not causing any issue. If I reduced the title of the component then it working fine.

Comment: What is the full error you get (in the Tridion Event Log)? And what is the length of the path of the item? The maximum length of the path of an item is 1000 characters (that is: the unencoded URL path of a WebDAV URL).

Comment: It is around 500+ Length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Special characters are not causing any issue. If I reduced the title of the component then it working fine